# Possible to choose between iOS base sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

i´ve updated Xcode to the latest version and therefore the base SDK is iOS6.
I just want to know, if it´s still possible to compile an app with the old iOS5 SDK?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes of cause it's works fine.

Comment: Yes you can if but you have to check component for you xcode.

You can check from xcode - >Downloads -> Component, You can install here as well if not availalbe

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply. I´ve just opened the Downloads/Components panel. But there´s only "iOS 5.0" & "iOS 5.1 simulator" and "command line tools". What should be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No with xcode 4.5 you can only compile with the iOS 6 SDK, but you can still target the iOS 5 device by setting the deployment target to iOS 5 (or 4.3).

This will allow you to run the app on iOS 5, but make sure that you do not call any methods that are iOS 6 only.

Comment: Yeah, i know. Thanks. But i just need to compile my current app with iOS 5 (no need for iOS6 features. It would take my additional time to reorganize some stuff due the deprecated "viewDidUnload". )

Comment: Don't worry, you can still use the `viewDidUnload` in you project with iOS 6. It will just give you a warning. But if you set the deployment to anything lower then iOS 6 the warning seem to be gone.

Comment: Ok thanks @rchoenes. So it seems that there´s no way to compile with an old SDK completely. Thanks

Comment: No Apple even rejected one of my app for being not being compiled for  iOS 6 and not running correctly on the iPhone 5. You can only get your app running on the iPhone 5 if you compile with the iOS 6 SDK. You could if you still have an old copy of Xcode 4.4 use that to compile against iOS 5 or copy the iOS 5 SDK from that xcode.app to the 4.5 app, but this might not be as easy and could fail.